# Local variable statusMessage defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final on returning a new object

Tags: java, spring

I have the following route on a Spring Boot application:

```java
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@GetMapping("/status")
public Object status() {
    String statusMessage = "disconnected";
    String error = null;

    try {
        Db db = new Db();
        if (db.isConnected()) {
            statusMessage = "ok";
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        error = e.getMessage();
    }

    return new Object() {
        public String project = applicationName;
        public String version = buildVersion;
        public String connection = statusMessage;
        public String message = error;
    };
}
```

However the lines `public String connection = statusMessage;` and `public String message = error;` have the following error:

```
Local variable statusMessage defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final
```

How can I fix this besides creating a new final variable that receives whatever `error` or `statusMessage` has before using it in the new Object?

Note: The reason why I am returning a new Object is because its the simplest way I could find to return a POJO for spring to turn it into JSON without having to create a class for every route return.

Comment: Create an intermediate variable, assign it the value of `statusMessage`, then assign that to the `connection` field. But, also, don't. Create custom POJO types. Use their constructors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end creating an actual class instead of a anonymous object was the correct choice.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways around this, but in my opinion, you should not be coding this the way you have it.

You can use an AtomicReference to create a Reference to a String.

```
AtomicReference<String> statusMessage = new AtomicReference<>();
AtomicReference<String> error = new AtomicReference<>();
```

....

```
statusMessage.set("Disconnected");
error.set(e.getMessage());
```

....

```
return new Object() {
   public String connection = statusMessage.get();
   public String message = error.get();
};
```

This will solve your issue, but returning a raw Object is going to cause many more headaches for you.  Create a POJO, even if it's a simple DTO, for your responses.  This will enable you to provide better API documentation, as well as write effective unit tests, as well as provide type-checking.